# App to search for zeroconf devices

Tags: tcp, bonjour, avahi, zeroconf

I have some equipment running Linux on a SOC which connects to my mini network using avahi zeroconf. I know it's zeroconf 'name' by scanning in Safari for windows (which doesn't fully work any more for some reason & is unsupported). The network has no DNS/ DHCP server. Is there tool which could find the devices IP address from its name other than just scanning the entire possible range with something like angry ip scanner? Also is there any way to 'force' a zeroconf device like this to take an ipaddress at least within a preferred range other than hacking into it's proprietary programming written by the OEM.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: sorry David, I'll know for next time.  For anyone who happens to end up on this page - 'BonjourBrowser' seems to crash in W7 on my weird network but this works nicely: www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/zeroconfservicebrowser.html